# UIWebView Search text and navigate through next occurrences using next button

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have successfully implemented UIWebView Search text, Now i want to navigate through all the next occurrence and previous, Can any one suggest something in UIWebView. help greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the result using this javascript function

```
function goNext(){
    jump(1);
}
function goPrev(){
    jump(-1);
}

function jump(nextOrPrev){


    prevSelected = currSelected;
    currSelected = currSelected + nextOrPrev;

    if (currSelected < 0){
        currSelected = uiWebview_SearchResultCount + currSelected;
    }
    if (currSelected >= uiWebview_SearchResultCount){
        currSelected = currSelected - uiWebview_SearchResultCount;
    }

    prevEl = document.getElementsByClassName("uiWebviewHighlight")[prevSelected];
    if (prevEl){
        prevEl.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
    el = document.getElementsByClassName("uiWebviewHighlight")[currSelected];
    el.style.backgroundColor="green";
    el.scrollIntoView(true); 
}
```

Do initialise currSelected=-1 in the beginning of your search function before element comparison, which should be something like this

```
if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) { //your code} }
```